# Adding creation time, modification time column to existing table in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table with some records. Now I want to add 'created' and 'updated' columns to it. I am using queries like this

```
ALTER TABLE employee ADD COLUMN updated TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT 
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

But this is creating columns with value as all zeros. I want it to be current timestamp.

Sample:

```
mysql> select * from employee;  
+----+------+  
| id | name |  
+----+------+  
|  1 | a    |  
|  2 | b    |  
|  3 | c    |  
+----+------+  
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)  

mysql> alter table employee add column updated timestamp not null default current_timestamp on update current_timestamp;  
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.20 sec)  
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0  

mysql> select * from employee;  
+----+------+---------------------+  
| id | name | updated             |  
+----+------+---------------------+  
|  1 | a    | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |  
|  2 | b    | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |  
|  3 | c    | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |  
+----+------+---------------------+  
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)  

mysql> update employee set name='aa' where id='1';  
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)  
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0  

mysql> select * from employee;  
+----+------+---------------------+  
| id | name | updated             |  
+----+------+---------------------+  
|  1 | aa   | 2015-12-10 15:41:44 |  
|  2 | b    | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |  
|  3 | c    | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |  
+----+------+---------------------+  
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)  

mysql> alter table employee add column city varchar(10) not null default 'banglore';  
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.17 sec)  
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0  

mysql> select * from employee;  
+----+------+---------------------+----------+  
| id | name | updated             | city     |  
+----+------+---------------------+----------+  
|  1 | aa   | 2015-12-10 15:41:44 | banglore |  
|  2 | b    | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | banglore |  
|  3 | c    | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | banglore |  
+----+------+---------------------+----------+  
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Seems like DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is not working

Comment: Works fine on my machine (F23 with `mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.0.21-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1`). What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.44, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3

Comment: The manual (for your version) covers all this in considerable detail

Comment: In the manual I found "Invalid DATE, DATETIME, or TIMESTAMP values are converted to the “zero” value of the appropriate type
('0000-00-00' or '0000-00-00 00:00:00')." but there were no warnings or errors during alter.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE `employee` ADD `COLUMN` 
TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```